# Is it possible to query the Collection-Types of strapi

Tags: rest, graphql, strapi

Is it possible to query a list of **Collection-Types** in Strapi?

**The following example:**

I have three **Collection-Types**:

- Restaurant
- Stores
- Events

The client application does **not** know which Collection-Types exist and I want to query them dynamically:

**Example response**

```
{
    contentTypes: [
        {
            name: "Restaurant"
        },
        {
            name: "Stores"
        },
        {
            name: "Events"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible with Strapi? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @AsheAbbottDiBlasi Unfortunately not. :-( Have you had any luck?

Comment: I didn't have any luck. We ended up building our own solution with React instead of using Strapi.

Comment: @AsheAbbottDiBlasi We also had to write our own solution with React & Express.js. LOL. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Good luck to you, too!

Answer (score 1):

Well there does not seem to be a native way of doing this. But some **hacky solution** could be to fetch all existing types and filter them somehow.

E.g. fetching the names of all types

```
query Types {
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Now every type that contains the phrase `EntityResponseCollection` is possibly a collection type. Exclude plugin related types and file collection types and you should be able to get all your content types.

Example in JavaScript

```
// your schema response from the above query
const data = { __schema: { types: [ ... ] } } 

// types, you want to exclude
const blacklist = ['UploadFile', 'UploadFolder', 'I18NLocale', 'UsersPermissions'];

// your filter function
const collectionTypes = data.__schema.types.filter(type => {
    if (blacklist.some(item => type.name.includes(item))) return false;
    if (!type.name.includes("EntityResponseCollection")) return false;
    return true
})
```

Not very elegant but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can create a collection to store all other collection-type names.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35164398)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).